# gaussian noise in systemVerilog

Tags: system-verilog, real-number

I'm writing a Gaussian noise generator in verilog,

the code work fine when the output is a vector of logic (16 bit)

but i need this code to communicate with another block which is using Real inputs

i had tryed the $bitstoreal function but it is not working, the output is always O

what i had done is replacing output [16, 0] data_out1 by output real data_out1 in module in/out declaration, and add "assign  data_out1 = $bitstoreal(data_out);" data_out is a bit vector coming from an other module

any help

Comment: Please could you post the code you have tried so far.

Answer (score -1):

data_out should be [15,0] to be 16 bits

Comment: [15,0] is not a range in Verilog/SystemVerilog; use a column: ` [15:0]`